# Using a pure function as an option of a function

Tags: options, pure-function

Here's my code:

```
Options[f] = {"Func" -> Exp};

f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["Func"][x]

f[2, "Func" -> (# + 2) &]
```

I expected to get 4 as a return. Instead, it doesn't evaluate anything and returns

```
f[0, "Func" -> #1 + 2 &]
```

And the funny thing is that it works just fine when the option is a built-in function instead of a pure function:

```
Options[f] = {"Func" -> Exp};

f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["Func"][x];

f[2, "Func" -> Abs]
```

```
2
```

Can someone explain what's wrong with my code?

Comment: People often make errors like this when passing pure functions to plotting functions. For instance, feeding something like `ColorFunction -> Hue[# + 1/2] &` or `RegionFunction ->  2 < #1^2 + #2^2 < 9 &` to those functions when they should have respectively been `ColorFunction -> (Hue[# + 1/2] &)` or `RegionFunction ->  (2 < #1^2 + #2^2 < 9 &)`.

Comment: For completeness, here's the [entire operator precedence table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html). Instead of learning it by heart, using repeated Ctrl-. keypresses you can select progressively wider areas of a command, which makes operator precedence obvious. See ["Extend Selection"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/ExtendSelection.html) on the [Keyboard Shortcut Listing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `f[2, "Func" -> (# + 2) &] // FullForm` to discover that operator precedence has bitten you. You have written effectively `("Func" -> #1 + 2) &`, not `"Func" -> ((#1 + 2)&)`.

By the way, the other shorthand for `Function`, namely `f[2, "Func" -> x \[Function] x + 2]`, also fails, but with a much more explicit message: "Parameter specification `Func->x` in `Function[Func->x,x+2]` should be a symbol or a list of symbols."

Comment: Yeah, when passing functions as arguments, I usually prefer the verbose form `Function[...]` because of this.